# RTSP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable Invalid Server Response in streaming application

Tags: java, client, rtsp, server

I am using two to java files (server.java and client.java) for Video Streaming.

While running Server.java there is no problem.. While pressing Setup button from client i got a exception like below,

```
RTSP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable
Invalid Server Response
```

i Think  RTSPBufferedWriter.write is the problem

```
private void send_RTSP_request(String request_type) {
        try {
            //Use the RTSPBufferedWriter to write to the RTSP socket

            //write the request line:


            RTSPBufferedWriter.write(request_type + " " + VideoFileName + " RTSP/1.0" + CRLF);
            //.....



            }

            RTSPBufferedWriter.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //System.out.println("Exception caught : " + ex);

            notify = "Exception caught : " + ex;
            setChanged();
            notifyObservers(notify);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

can any one help me to solve the above issue?

Thanks.

Comment: ou should provide more details, for example - at least the RTSP session commands before the error occurs (DESCRIBE, SETUP?). Are you sure the track is available, since you have pasted only the response, not the request.